# Get SQL Server database created Information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a database in  SQL Server 2012 with name "yadav". Now I want to know where "Yadav" DB info is stored like Created Date, Number of Tables, User Name etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/12/sql-server-get-all-the-information-of-database-using-sys-databases/

Comment: google `SQL Server Catalog views` , (sys.tables , sys.columns , sys.schemas etc ..)

Comment: You can get some of this info by right clicking and choosing "properties".

Answer (score 1):

You can get the database information from sys.databases table.

```
select * 
from sys.databases
where name = database_name
```

and table information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table.

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_CATALOG = database_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Some basic things are accessible in the `sys.databases` catalog view:

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_date
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'yadav'
```

For other, you'll have to go to your database:

```
USE yadav;

SELECT TableCount = COUNT(*)
FROM sys.tables
```

and there's a vast collection of other *system catalog views* which provide insight into your database and its objects

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
sp_helpdb 'Yadav'
```